# Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Bad Request [400]

Tags: youtube-api, http-status-code-404, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client, bad-request

I use https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client to get some videos from Youtube channel.

This is my code:

```
var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    ApplicationName = "My Application",
    ApiKey = "MyKey",
    GZipEnabled = true
});
var searchResultList = youtubeService.Search.List("id");
searchResultList.ChannelId = "mychannelid";
searchResultList.Order = SearchResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum.Date;
searchResultList.Type = "video";
searchResultList.MaxResults = 50;

var ids = string.Join(",", searchResultList.Execute().Items.Select(x => x.Id.VideoId));

var videoRequest = youtubeService.Videos.List("snippet, contentDetails");
videoRequest.Id = ids;
videoRequest.MaxResults = 50;

return videoRequest.Execute().Items.ToList();
```

An application execute this code every twenty minutes. So the amount of request can't be more than the quotas.
But, unfortunately, I often receive this error:

```
Message: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Bad Request [400]
Errors [
Message[Bad Request] Location[ - ] Reason[keyInvalid] Domain[usageLimits]
]

Exception type: Google.GoogleApiException
Stack Trace: 
at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() in     C:\Users\mdril\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line 102
```

There are some similar questions here, but it doesn't help.

Comment: where did you get the key?  Reason[keyInvalid]  should have given you a hint as to the problem.

Comment: here [https://console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com) This method sometimes works, but often it throws the error.

Comment: I would double check it.  Remember you should have created API key credentials not OAUTH2 or Service account.

Comment: Yes, I created only API key, and it doesn't matter what key is  browser or server.

Comment: browser contains a redirect uri server will just redirect to where ever you are sending it from.  It would depend on the type of your application.  Make sure your code isn't running to fast Domain usage limits makes me think its flood protection if you are only getting it occasionally.     However Keyinvalid is a clear sign there is something wrong with the key

Comment: My application is ASP.NET website. And I execute the code inside a task. Can this execution affect on it? The process of creation API Keys is easy, so I do not understand where the problem can be.

Comment: @DalmTo thanks for your help. I've found the bug. We used a website context related value inside the task)

Comment: @AntonGrekhovodov I have encountered the same issue, can you please elaborate regarding how you solved it.

Comment: @Dror it was just a wrong key in our code, because its value was overriden in website settings. You should check your key too.